# Changing legend title in a leaflet map in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a list of possible coloring options in a map in `shiny` + `leaflet`, such as

```
vars <- c("Difference"  = "diff",
          "Index"       = "index",
          "City Cargo"  = "cid_carga",
          "City score"  = "carga_mun_score")
```

From the above variables I create a selection list, which will be used to select the desired variable to be colored in the map

```
selectInput("color", "Color", vars, selected = "carga_mun_score")
```

However, and obviously, when I create the legend title in the `leaflet` map, the title stays as the actual name of the variable, *e.g.*, "cid_cargo" instead of "City Cargo".

```
addLegend("bottomleft",pal = pal, values = df[[input$color]], title = input$color,
                          layerId = "colorLegend")
```

[image]

Is there a way to use my *alias* (in the example above "city score") name instead of the actual variable name ("carga_mun_score"), without using a really long `if` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
addLegend("bottomleft",pal = pal, values = df[[input$color]], 
                          layerId = "colorLegend", title="City Score")
```

Or save your selection to a variable that can translate the names:

```
varname<-switch(input$color,
           "diff" = "Difference",
           "index"="Index",
          "cid_carga"="City Cargo",
          "carga_mun_score"="City score")
```

Then pass that variable to your leaflet legend:

```
    addLegend("bottomleft",pal = pal, values = df[[input$color]],
                              layerId = "colorLegend", title=varname)
```

Comment: why do you have two `title` arguments inside `addLegend`?

Comment: well, your answer is wrong in the switch case, syntax was reversed. Your first "simply" solution does not address the question and those two titles are wrong. If you edit it correcting those steps I can accept your answer

Comment: Whoops, blame the lack of coffee. I  misread your question but to answer 1) using input$.. directly in a plot/leaflet may cause issues with quotations especially if you are using these inputs in other functions to pipe into leaflet